# Setting JRE to a different version

Tags: java

I have set my

JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43
```

JRE_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
```

PATH

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;C:\maven\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;
```

but when I try to check the Java version it points to

```
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

I'm wondering why it still points to 1.7 when the JRE & JAVA_HOME variables are pointing to version 6.

Comment: Check to see if there is a java.exe in the Windows System directory.  You might have to adjust the SYSTEM PATH to have the Java bin directory before your Windows System

Comment: I tried this %windir%\system and that folder is empty...

Comment: Check C:\Windows\System32 then

Comment: Are you changing the system PATH or user's? Restart the console after changing any environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reboot your computer after changing PATH

Comment: Or simply open a new DOS window.